# Get loaded package's function X title programmatically

Tags: r

How can I get the title of a function from a loaded package programmatically?  For example `?mean` tells me **Arithmetic Mean** and `?sd`'s title is **Standard Deviation**.  How could I use R to return `"Arithmetic Mean"` given the function name `mean`?

Comment: You can use the index page of the package, for example `grep("^sd", readLines(system.file("INDEX", package = "stats")), value = TRUE)
`  The title is right.

Comment: Actually the above suggestion has issues, like `var` is not listed since the page is called `cor`.  And multi-line titles will be split up.  But I'll leave the comment there just in case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it using the following:

You will need the `Rd_db` function from the tools package to find the rd file of one of the functions (the `mean` in this case):

```
library(tools)
db <- Rd_db("base")
```

Then save in a variable the .Rd file of interest

```
therd <- db[grep("mean.Rd", names(db), value = TRUE)]
```

Finally just print the Title

```
> c(therd$mean.Rd[[1]][[1]])
[1] "Arithmetic Mean"
```

In the same way you can actually print other parts of the .Rd file like the description, value etc.